# Does a thread invoking, synchronized method, pre-empt another thread using same object but in a non synchronized manner?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

In Java, Does a thread invoking, synchronized method, pre-empt another thread using same object but in a non synchronized manner?

Also, when a thread is invoking a synchronized method or synchronized block, does the thread explicitly owns the entire object?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Answer (score 2):

> In Java, Does a thread invoking, synchronized method, pre-empt another
>   thread using same object but in a non synchronized manner?

No, one thread (assuming no data-races/race-conditions) knows nothing about what another thread is doing outside of synchronization.

> Also, when a thread is invoking a synchronized method or synchronized
>   block, does the thread explicitly owns the entire object?

If by own you mean mutual exclusion, than no, it only has ownership to synchronized regions.

Answer (score 0):

First question: no

Second question cannot be answered, because "owned" is not well defined.